# Star Trek cookbook pet food question

Tags: cats, diet, eating

In the *Star Trek Cookbook,* there's a cat food recipe under the Data character entry. My question is, how effective is it as a homemade cat food? Would it work as dog food?

---

The recipe (Catfood #219, subroutine |DataSpot\Nancy|):

> 1 pound liver, kidneys, hearts, haggis or other organs
>
> water to boil meat in
>
> 2 cups bran
>
> 2 cups old fashioned oatmeal or rolled oats
>
> 1/4 cup canola or other cooking oil

---

> Boil meat in saucepan with water until cooked, cool, then mince/grind
> up.
>
> Mix in water used for boiling and other ingredients until you have a
> dough like mixture.
>
> Preheat oven to 250 degrees
>
> Form kibble or bite sized biscuits from the dough.
>
> Arrange biscuits on oiled baking sheet and bake for 3 hours
>
> Turn off oven but leave sheet inside, then air-dry biscuits for
> another 24 hours.

Comment: Any more thoughts on this question?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to add whether the degrees are Celsius or Fahrenheit in case someone wanted trying out the recipe. I had the feeling that it should be Celsius, but it was bugging me and then I noticed "bake for 3 hours" and I guess after 3 hours in 250 Celsius they would be burnt to crisp, so my feeling makes no sense and I undone my modifications. Apologies for this, I shouldn't have touched it. Could you please add explicit temperature units if you know the details? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was going by what’s in the book that the recipe came from. Your probably right about Fahrenheit though.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for your response. And the more I think about it, the more I'm assured it's indeed in Fahrenheit, but I am even more assured that I shouldn't have touched it without solid source at the first place, so I will leave it as it was. ^.^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Addressing the recipe part only:

Cats in the future must have undergone significant changes in their digestion and hungriness. ;)

- Cats can't really use the bran or oats, so they're essentially just filler.
- 1 pound of organs is quite a lot for a cat (and there's also the filler stuff).

Overall I'd say this is clearly meant as some kind of treat and definitely no full food replacement and definitely not a single meal (poor Spot!)

Considering the ingredients I'd say it's better fit for dogs than cats (they'll be able to utilize all the nutrients).

Comment: This recipe is clearly for dry catfood. You can't make a dry biscuit or pellet type catfood without some sort of "filler" source of fiber, though with commercial dry catfood, usually it's grain or corn.